# Reset Sonicwall TZ600

Tags: networking, sonicwall

Looking to reset a SonicWall TZ600 I won it recently at an IT auction.
I plugged into the X0 Lan via my laptop not getting a connection seems like no DHCP.
The SonicWall does light up and I see network activity on the machine.

Looked online for documentation to do a hard reset. Couldn't find much for TZ600 just for the lesser models.

I did a place in the back of device to stick a paperclip in which might reset.   I hold it for 30 seconds and the wrench icon flashes. But nothing else happens. I have let it sit overnight. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect via console cable.  Also, unplug all cable to it and power it up.  The wrench light should not stay on.

Answer (score 0):

There is a little sonicwall soft that can detect on which network is the TZ.
To use the reset, each TZ has his way, see the notice.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).